# Reference Eclipse UserLibrary in IDEA

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, classpath

I am migrating to IDEA from Eclipse and have a few Eclipse UserLibraries that I want to easily reference.

I tried adding Libraries bt Attaching Classes and Jar Directories, but it seems IDEA doesn't pick up the class files? Even after I re-compile etc.

Am I doing something wrong?

What is the best and correct way of going about this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Libraries that you configure in this dialog should be then [added to the module dependencies](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html).